# Getting error when trying to use pointer with struct

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I am trying to code RGB values into a struct and it is working fine but I get an exception saying my struct was nullptr when I try to run a function that accesses that struct. Here is the code:

```
struct Color {
    unsigned char R;
    unsigned char G;
    unsigned char B;
}*blue, *red, *green, *yellow, *purple, *pink, *brown;

void CreateColors()
{
    blue->R = 0;
    blue->G = 0;
    blue->B = 255;

    red->R = 255;
    red->G = 0;
    red->B = 0;

    green->R = 0;
    green->G = 255;
    green->B = 0;

    yellow->R = 255;
    yellow->G = 255;
    yellow->B = 0;

    purple->R = 133;
    purple->G = 87;
    purple->B = 168;

    pink->R = 255;
    pink->G = 0;
    pink->B = 191;

    brown->R = 168;
    brown->G = 130;
    brown->B = 87;

}
```

If you guys could tell me what I am doing wrong or a better data structure to use that would be great. I am TA'ing a cpp class and am trying to subtly start using pointers to warm them up. Thanks again.

Also when I try to use these values like so:

```
if (deg >= 0 && deg < boundaries[COAL_B])
{
    pixels[i][j][0] = blue->R;
    pixels[i][j][1] = blue->G;
    pixels[i][j][2] = blue->B;
}
```

It throws the same error.

Comment: You are not allocating any space for the structures.

Comment: " I am TA'ing a cpp class and am trying to subtly start using pointers to warm them up" - this looks like an awful way of doing that, and it seems you don't have the minimal knowledge needed to teach C++ (or C).

Comment: Not to be rude but if you are going to TA a C++ class you really should understand C++.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought when you declare a pointer of a certain data type it allocates enough memory to store that pointer. Are you saying I should use new and manually allocate memory? @EugeneSh.

Comment: We are saying you might want to read a book on C++ (or C) before attempting to teach it.

Comment: You have both `c++` and `c` tags.  Those are different languages.  The class you are TA'ing is a C++ class.  Why the `c` tag?

Comment: Yes, enough memory is allocated to store a pointer. A pointer to a structure. Now what you need to do is (a) allocate a structure and (b) point the pointer at the structure. Then you can start initializing the r,g,b values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a series of pointers to `struct Color`, but you're not initializing any of them, so because they're defined at file scope they are all set to NULL.  You then attempt to dereference those NULL pointers.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should instead define instances of these structs instead of pointers:

```
struct Color {
    unsigned char R;
    unsigned char G;
    unsigned char B;
} blue, red, green, yellow, purple, pink, brown;
```

Then access them as instances:

```
void CreateColors()
{
    blue.R = 0;
    blue.G = 0;
    blue.B = 255;

    red.R = 255;
    red.G = 0;
    red.B = 0;

    ...
```

Better yet, get rid of the initialization function and initialize them at the point they're defined:

```
struct Color {
    unsigned char R;
    unsigned char G;
    unsigned char B;
};

struct Color blue = { 0, 0, 255}, red = { 255, 0, 0 }, green = { 0, 255, 0}, ...
```

Comment: "You should instead define instances of these structs i" - really don't think he should be declaring global instances of these structs either.

Comment: nah global instance of this struct is exactly what i need in this case. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Also, when using structs the default behavior when initializing them is to fill up the variables in the order they are in the struct? I kinda jumped to classes so I don't really know the details of struct behavior.

Comment: @MaxAttax Yes, fields are initialized in the order they are defined in.  Also, feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a pointer to a structure but never allocate memory for it.  When you access it's members, you're dereferencing a null pointer.